# Review queue “Documentation: Proposed Changes” appears to forget reviews (temporarily)

Tags: bug, documentation, proposed-changes

#### Observed behaviour

I recently reviewed [this proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/123970).
I decided to reject for plagiarism and saw afterwards that I seemed to be the only person to have reviewed this.
But when I looked into [the history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history),
it showed two others had approved an item of the same name.
When clicking the relevant links provided,
it linked to *my* review with *their* approve votes *still missing*.

I decided to ask on meta

> Why did this happen?
>   Have their votes been invalidated due to my “inappropriately copied content” vote?
>
> (If the answer to the latter question is not “yes”,
>   I will request this feature.)

While I wrote this post,
I continued checking the review item and after a while,
another person rejected with the same comment as I.
This showed up just fine, the approves were still missing.

Before I finished my post,
the proposal was rejected (yet another person disliked plagiarism).
And all of a sudden, the approve votes were shown.

#### Expected behaviour

I expected their votes to be shown all the time.

When they did not show up,
I expected them to be gone for good.

#### Actual Question

Why did this happen?

*(To make this post not “too broad”,
I will make the feature request its own post,
should I still feel the need to do so after having understood why this happened the way it did.)*